# How to mark a field as validated (for accessing in validated_data) in validate(self)?

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework, custom-fields

Let's say I have a field I want to validate/clean. I'd normally go about it like this for a field I know I will use.

```
def validate_number(self, value):
   if value == 7:
     raise serializers.ValidationError('7 is bad!')
   if value == 5:
     return None  # I want 5 to come back as None
   return value
```

Let's say I'm not sure which fields I have on validation and I go through these fields in validate(), How would I achieve this same behavior?

```
def validate(self, data):
  if data['number'] == 7:
     raise serializers.ValidationError('7 is bad!')
  if data['number'] == 5:
     data['number'] = None
  return data
```

Would I be able to access this as validated_data in a .create/.update method?

Comment: From the [django docs on form and field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation), in the second bullet point, "The validate() method... does not return anything and shouldn’t alter the value." It doesn't look like using `validate()` is your answer. Providing more detail may inspire alternate solutions.

Comment: If you are talking about validation on a DRF serializer, it should work. The [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation) do not say you must not modify data. If I recall correctly I used that to build an [hiddenfield](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#hiddenfield) from other custom values passed to the serializer, and even removed some values.

Answer (score 0):

You should raise a `ValidationError` with a dictionary:

```
     raise serializers.ValidationError({'number': '7 is bad!'})
```

Then, the return value of validate will be passed as `validated_data` which you'll have access once `is_valid()` is `True`.

Comment: Oops, yeah. I meant to type that. What I'm trying to ask, is how to properly pass the cleaned value to my create/update functions. In other words, how to mark the field I clean as a validated field.

Comment: Edited the response although I'm not sure about your question.

Comment: Isn't the return value of validate the raw data + any edits I make though? Is there a way to only have fields I edit make it to validated_data? What if certain fields are invalid and I don't want to mark them as valid?